# Creating histogram for continuous raster dataset in Create Graphs wizard of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, graph

I would like to create some histograms of continuous raster data (in TIFF format) to display in a report.

When I enter the Create Graphs wizard, I can only display histograms for feature classes, not rasters. I understand that I can also use 'Create Histogram' function but this does not give me all of the options for visual edits such as colour.

Is there a way I can create and edit a histogram for this raster data? It is a massive amount of data to export and I have had no success trying to make the histograms in Excel or SPSS (they just crash!).

Comment: I would think that you could use the Histograms tool (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/histograms.htm), which will require the Geostatistical Analyst license.

Comment: Yes I have been able to use this tool for analysis, but I am interested in creating nice-looking histograms for display purposes.